# How to fix image download python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I can't save the image i got from soup object, the image source is correct if i copy it and paste it in browser,however i can't seem to download it

I  used `BeautifulSoup` to find the image then `requests` to download it,i also tried to download it with `urllib.urlretrieve` but didn't work finally i used `lxml.html` to parse and get the image and download it using binary decoding

```
import bs4,urllib2,requests
REGISTER_URL="http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/user/register?_next=/places/default/index%22"
html=urllib2.urlopen(REGISTER_URL)
soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
image=soup.find("img",src=True)
print image['src']
#print image['src']
response=requests.get(image['src'])
'''
f=open("Cas.jpg")
for block in response.iter_content(1024):
    f.write(block)
f.close()
'''
```

i want to know why `requests` and `urllib.urlretrieve` to download it doesn't work,Note: `urllib.urlretrieve` downloads a black image while requests just gives an error.
My expected results is simply *download the CAPTCHA image*

**Note1**:the image is the CAPTCHA from [Python web-scraping example](http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/user/register?_next=/places/default/index%22), and of course a new image is received every time you load the page.

**Note2**: this is in no way an attack or an act of anything harmful on the site, this site is made as an example to test scrapers.

Comment: For those who are giving -rep please explain why ,in comments so i can work on my "questions" in the furutre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image is present as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) on the site. You could get the data string from `src` , decode it and then save as image.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import base64
url = "http://example.webscraping.com/places/default/user/register?_next=/places/default/index%22"
r=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
imgstring=soup.find('img')['src'].split(',')[1]
filename = 'image.jpg'
imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(imgdata)
```

image.jpg

[image]

Comment: it works well, i have to ask how did you know it was `base64` ,also can you elaborate more on `imgdata = base64.b64decode(imgstring)`

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash Yes. The Binary image data is encoded into ASCII and used in the image source. We have to decode it back to get the binary data. Only then can we convert it back to file.

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash The image src was not a url. You can use the inspect tool to figure it out.

Comment: but if you copy paste the src in firefox it will open the image

Comment: @AmjasdMasdhash Browser does the decoding. Requests does not.